# Mongoclient: how to set a value of an embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im using the MongoClient in nodejs. I want to update an specific embedded document value, but I don't know how to do that.
In the mongo shell it works like a charm With `{$set{doc.doc : "test"}}`

But when I'm trying to use it in exactly the same way in node, It gives me the error that the dot isn't undestandable.

I've tried it as a string, which doesn't work either.

Does somebody got a solution for this problem?

EDIT:
Json doc in the Mongodb:

```
{
  name : test,
  doc : {},
}
```

and I want to add the following key-value pair to the 'doc'-document
`test:test`

Relevant Code part (How i thought It should work)

```
db.collection("test").update({name:test},{$set:{doc.test:test}}, callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting up the update object in a variable using the array-syntax style, e.g:

```
var update = { $set: {} };
update["$set"]["doc"]["test"] = "test"; // -> same as update = {"$set": {"doc": {"test": "test" } } }
var query = {"name": "test"};
db.collection("test").update(query, update, callback);
```

Comment: I don't know that it is possible to use set with the embedded structure (as you mentioned in your outcommented)
Of course this sounds very logic, so I will try it out tomorrow.